# Criteria Builder select from select

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

Can anybody help me to create JPA Criteria Builder query in order to achieve this ?:

```
select id from (
  select distinct r.id
                  r.date
                  r.name
  from report r
  inner join unit u
        on u.report_id = r.id
  order by 
        r.date desc,
        r.name asc)
where rownum <= 10
```

I just can create inner query:

```
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> innerQuery = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<ReportEntity> root = innerQuery.from(ReportEntity.class);

List<Ojbect[]> resultLsit = em.createQuery(
innerQuery.multiselect(root.get(ReportEntity_.id),
                       root.get(ReportEntity_.date),
                       root.get(ReportEntity_.name)
                       .distinct(true)
                       .orderBy(cb.desc(root.get(ReportEntity_.date)),
                                cb.asc(root.get(ReportEntity.name))

).setMaxResults(10).getResultList();
```

Thx in advance :)
I've decided to get List of Object[] and then retrieve id from array
List idList = resultList.stream().map(array -> (Long)array[0]).collect(Collectors.toList());
This is code smell, but unfortunatelly I haven't found better solution.
Note I use this approach to cope Hibernate issue :

"Warning “firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!”? - this warning pops up due to using fetch and setMaxResults in hql or criteria query.
That's why first of all I get all id, and then I find all entities according this id. (select * from ReportEntity r where r.id in :idList) - smth like this.

Comment: JPQL does NOT support/allow subqueries in the FROM clause. All that your outer query is seemingly doing is restricting the range of the query, and JPQL provides firstResult/maxResults for that. So what is the issue with your criteria provided?

Comment: so if hibernate doesn't support handling maxResults/firstResult in the query for that database then you use a NATIVE query

Comment: You are right, but I create Criteria Builder query, cause I have search page with filters